# $(A-B) \cup (B-A) = (A\cup B) - (A \cap B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

So it is as it seen in the title. Here is why I am stuck:

Let $x \in [(A-B) \cup (B-A)] \Longrightarrow x \in (A-B)$ or $x \in (B-A) $ $\Longrightarrow$ ($x \in A$ and $x \not \in B$) or ($x \not \in A$ and $x \in B$).

Here is where I am stuck. Can I product these parenthesis? Like:

(x in A or x not in A) and ( x in A or x in B) and (x not in B or x not in A) and (x not in B or x in B).

And please, how I can learn write with symbols? Cant find the button. So sorry.

Comment: Yes, you did fine.  For "in" use `\in` = $\in$, for union, use `cup` = $\cup$, , for intersection, use `cap` = $\cap$.  For "or" use `\lor` = $\lor$, and for "and", use `\land` = $\land$.  Then just remember to surround formulas by a dollar sign at the start and at the end.

Comment: \bigcup $\rightarrow \bigcup$,  and \bigcap $\rightarrow \bigcap.$  Put a dollar sign on the left and right, and you have it.

Comment: Hahaha, @amWhy beat me to it.

Comment: Also note that $x \in A \lor x \notin A$ is always true.  Similarly, your last parentheses should read (x not in B **or** x in B), or $x\notin B \lor x\in B$, which is also always true.

Comment: Hehehe, @mjw.  Typically, \bigcup and \bigcap or for unions or intersections of families of sets.

Comment: Right!  I was thinking big!

Comment: @amWhy but maybe *too* big. I suggested edit and it looked too big.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "multiplying the parentheses" you can see each case separately:

- If $x\in A\text{ and }x\not\in B$, then $x\in A\cup B$ (because $A$ is a subset of $A\cup B$ and $x\in A$) and $x\not\in A\cap B$ (because $A\cap B$ is a subset of $B$ and $x\not\in B$), therefore $x\in (A\cup B)-(A\cap B)$.
- If $x\not\in A\text{ and }x\in B$, then $x\in A\cup B$ (because $B$ is a subset of $A\cup B$ and $x\in B$) and $x\not\in A\cap B$ (because $A\cap B$ is a subset of $A$ and $x\not\in A$), therefore $x\in (A\cup B)-(A\cap B)$.

In both cases you conclude that $x\in (A\cup B)-(A\cap B)$, which proves that every element of $(A-B)\cup (B-A)$ is and element of $(A\cup B)-(A\cap B)$.

The only thing left to prove that these two sets are equal is the converse, i.e that every element of $(A\cup B)-(A\cap B)$ is an element of $(A-B)\cup (B-A)$.